# Twitter API php oauth authentication fail

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

If my twitterInput value is a username, the authentication works fine. But if it's a hashtag, it fails. The search query is being encoded correctly, too.

Mine is ?q=%23hashtagName, not ?q=%2523hashtagName.  I realized I had too many encodings before.

All of the authentication code is being generated properly. I've tested the $base_string, $key, $signature, $url, $auth, and $options to see if they're holding correct values. As far I can read, they look fine.

I'm receiving the code 32 message, "could not authenticate you".

I was trying to see if there was a difference between all of my variables on whether or not I'm using a hashtag or username, and I can't spot a major difference, besides the obvious path difference.

Can anyone spot a glaring problem that would cause a hashtag to fail?

Thank you.

Here's my entire function:

```
<?php
function get_tweets($twitterInput){  
$token = 'XXXXXXXX';
$token_secret = 'XXXXXXXX';
$consumer_key = 'XXXXXXXX';
$consumer_secret = 'XXXXXXXX';

$host = 'api.twitter.com';
$method = 'GET';

$hashtagInput = null;
$usernameInput = null;
$twitterFirstCharacter = $twitterInput[0];

// detect whether the input was a hashtag, username with the @ symbol, or just username without @
if ($twitterFirstCharacter == "#") {
    $hashtagInput = $twitterInput;
} else if ($twitterFirstCharacter == "@") {
    // just in case there's a @ symbol, delete it
    $usernameInput = substr($twitterInput, 1);
} else {
    $usernameInput = $twitterInput;
}

$path = null;

// if hashtag, build a different path 
if ($hashtagInput) {
    $path = '/1.1/search/tweets.json'; // api call path
    $query = array( // query parameters
        "q" => $hashtagInput, 
        "count" => 3,
    );
} else {
     $path = '/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json'; // api call path
     $query = array( // query parameters
        'screen_name' => $usernameInput,
        'count' => 3
    );
}

$oauth = array(
    'oauth_consumer_key' => $consumer_key,
    'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
    'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
    'oauth_nonce' => time() . '-' . (string)mt_rand(), // a stronger nonce is recommended
    'oauth_version' => '1.0',
    'oauth_token' => $token,
  );

$arr = array_merge($oauth, $query); // combine the values THEN sort

asort($arr); // secondary sort (value)
ksort($arr); // primary sort (key)

$querystring = urldecode(http_build_query($arr, '', '&'));

$url = "https://$host$path";

$base_string = $method."&".urlencode($url)."&".urlencode($querystring);

  // same with the key
$key = rawurlencode($consumer_secret)."&".rawurlencode($token_secret);

  // generate the hash
$signature = rawurlencode(base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base_string, $key, true)));

$url = $url . "?" . http_build_query($query);

$oauth['oauth_signature'] = $signature; // don't want to abandon all that work!
ksort($oauth); // probably not necessary, but twitter's demo does it

  // also not necessary, but twitter's demo does this too
$oauth = array_map("_twitter_add_quotes", $oauth);

  // this is the full value of the Authorization line
$auth = "OAuth " . urldecode(http_build_query($oauth, '', ', '));

  // if you're doing post, you need to skip the GET building above
  // and instead supply query parameters to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS
$options = array( CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Authorization: $auth"),
                  //CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfields,
                  CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
                  CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false);

// do our business
$feed = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($feed, $options);
$json = curl_exec($feed);
curl_close($feed);

$twitter_data = json_decode($json);

return $twitter_data;
}
function _twitter_add_quotes($str) { return '"'.$str.'"'; }
?>
```

Comment: As @boussouira said in comment, get the available Twitter library for Php from [here](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/twitter-libraries#php) & start working on it. Why because, it's too simple and everything will be in few lines. I prefer `twitteroauth` by `@abraham`. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use a Twitter API library, take a look at [Twitter Developers](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/twitter-libraries#php) page, it has a good set of libraries for PHP and other languages.